# Transport security has blocked a cleartext HTTP

Tags: ios, xcode, ios9, ios10, app-transport-security

What setting do I need to put in my `info.plist` to enable HTTP mode as per the following error message?

> Transport security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource
>   load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via
>   your app's Info.plist file.

[image: Xcode]

Assume that my domain is `example.com`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31629980/1803879

Comment: **Moderator Note**: There are already 36 answers to this question. Before adding *another*, please make sure your solution is **new**.

Comment: **NOTE:** Solutions here suggest that you should turn ATS off (`Allow arbitary loads`). Soon this won't be possible since **Apple will require ATS**  (Originally the end of the year - deadline has been extended) - https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=12212016b

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/ios/app-transport-security

Comment: @Jeef why have you added iOS 10 tag? were there any additional changes in iOS 10 in that matter? I feel that it was introduced in iOS9 and that tag should be sufficient in terms of iOS versions

Answer (score 598, accepted):

If you are using Xcode 8.0+ and Swift 2.2+ or even Objective C:

[image]

If you want to allow HTTP connections to any site, you can use this keys:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

If you know which domains you will connect to add:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>example.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Comment: Why is `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` set to `true`? You subvert the purpose of ATS. Also see [The most dangerous code in the world: validating SSL certificates in non-browser software](http://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/pubs/abstracts/ssl-client-bugs.html). Your software just made the list.

Comment: @jww This is the purpose of this post. The site I need to connect to to play audio doesn't use HTTPS yet and I'm not trying to wait.

Comment: This will not work in iOS 10.0+ or MacOS 10.12+
It actually says to allow all arbitrary loads EXCEPT those mentioned (example.com). Thus it would do the reverse of what is desired.
NSAllowsArbirtraryLoads should be set to false here.

more info: [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW60)

Comment: Agree, why on earth is everybody upvoting this ? there is no point using NSAllowsArbitraryLoads if you set an exception domain.

Comment: NSAllowsArbitraryLoads does not need to be true, so it must be removed. NSExceptionDomains is enough which enables nonsecure connection to that domain only. NSAllowsArbitraryLoads = true will enable nonsecure connection to any domain so if still setting it to true makes the NSExceptionDomains nonsense to have as it includes all domains already

Comment: Works on Swift 5 smoothly

Answer (score 1017):

Use NSAppTransportSecurity:

[image]

You have to set the **NSAllowsArbitraryLoads** key to **YES** under **NSAppTransportSecurity** dictionary in your info.plist file.

[image: Plist configuration]

Comment: Let it be known: **THIS IS A WORKAROUND!** Anytime you're using HTTP over HTTPS you are opening up your user's device(s) to vulnerabilities. Sure it's unlikely in many cases but ethical programming is best practice. Just sayin' ... - also, +1 for the working (for testing purposes)

Comment: Thanks. Anyway ... Of course this is just a workaround. Production apps should always use https whenever possible. I only use this workaround for development phase.

Comment: This is NOT a solution - this is a HACK!  To add individual domain "exceptions" see this answer below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32560433/1103584

Comment: This is a bad answer because it chooses the LEAST secure solution to the problem and offers it alone, with absolutely no context which might inform the questioner as to what implications need to be considered when choosing this option, or what problems they might encounter.

Since there was already an answer that gave a more secure solution, but also included this solution with the necessary caveat, your answer was totally unnecessary and obsolete before ever being posted.

This is a bad answer.

Comment: While this solution is known to be vulnerable, it is the **only** solution I would recommend during **DEVELOPMENT**. Having to type in every exact domain during development is just silly (especially if you are using third party web services).

Comment: Although this solution is known as a "workaround", sometimes it's the *only* solution. My app uses third party web services, and need redirect users to URLs of all kinds of different product webs which might use http instead of https. It's impossible to explicitly write down all domain names in the exception list.

Comment: KMLong and whyceewhite have (and had at the time of this answer) both already given answers which include the information included here as well as a more secure solution which is better to use when possible, as well as an explanation of why the problem is happening in the first place and what needs to be considered when choosing how to address it. This answer on the other hand merely shoves some code that is easy to copy-paste without giving anyone any concept of what consequences it might have. Anyone who's serious about making a good product should care about understanding what they're doing

Comment: Name of those keys have changed now "App Transport Security Settings" under that "Allow Arbitrary Loads"

Comment: I just updated my apps to IOS 9. This security improvement seems pretty half baked (like the original iCloud APIs). I ended up using this override, although I tried putting individual sites. They failed intermittently with app transport errors, so I gave up. Guess we have to wait until IOS 10

Comment: @Jacksonkr: there are servers you can't control directly, you can't ask them to switch to https

Comment: @IanBell Technically you *can* ask them, but to your point they can always say no. My aim was to put caution out there, that is all.

Comment: @Jacksonkr: very often lots of open data are not https

Comment: Why are so many people against this solution? This definitely is NOT a hack! Many apps need to communicate to the actual internet where the security protocol is not always under your control. For example, it seems very reasonable to be able to show images from other servers that don't have an SSL certificate.

Comment: It is never going to work after this year. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254725/transport-security-has-blocked-a-cleartext-http/37830469#37830469

Comment: @ParaSara That is not true. You will simply need to provide a justification to Apple.  If you have a valid reason to disable ATS, they will allow it.  Now, it remains to be seen what Apple sees as a "valid reason".  Also, you can continue to disable the forward secrecy aspect of ATS with no need for justification.

Comment: @Oren You can trivially set up an image proxy, if you need to do that. People are against disabling ATS because it is a significant security risk, and it's not something you should ever do.

Comment: Yes, this is a workaround, the correct solution is not up to iOS development, the endpoint you are using should be secure HTTPS.

Comment: How do I achieve this exception functionality through config profile ? 
Considering config profile having same architecture like a .plist file, I tried adding `<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>` along with required parameters but still getting ATS error. Please help.

Comment: From the official Apple developer site: https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=jxky8h89. Here you can set exceptions for a specific domain.

Answer (score 859):

Here are the settings visually:

[image: visual settings for NSAllowsArbitraryLoads in info.plist via Xcode GUI]

Comment: I am using PhoneGap and this worked perfectly.  Exactly the trick to avoid the issue. Now I can build. Thank you!

Comment: I don't have that option.

Comment: If you open your Info.plist directly you can just add the **NSAppTransportSecurity** dictionary, and then create the **NSAllowsArbitraryLoads** item within that (see the answer edited by Umar Farooq, below).

Comment: The silver bullet worked for me, but the Exception domains did not.

Comment: Same here -- exception domains didn't work with 7.3 for me.

Comment: i was busy configuring info.plist which didnt work until i see this! thanks ;)

Comment: exception domains weren't working for me, either, but i figured out why - the domain I was trying to contact (in my case, covers.openlibrary.org) was only redirecting to a different domain (in my case, ol-covers1.us.archive.org) - when I added that 2nd domain as an exception domain, it worked.

Comment: @nickalchemist: It's working on iOs 9.3.1. Just met with the same problem.

Comment: i am using xcode 7, and while i was testing my app on an ipad I encounterd this problem, this particular solution helped me and fixed it.

Comment: It is never going to work after this year. http://stackoverflow.com/a/37830469/4947520

Comment: This option does not exist - XCode 7.3.1

Comment: **NOTE**: Soon this won't be possible since **Apple will require ATS** (Originally the end of the year - deadline has been extended) - https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=12212016b

Comment: Right click `App Transport Security Settings`, not `Bundle OS Type Code`

Comment: When you add an domain to the `Exception Domains`, you need to make it look like this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3q32sx1h5t6hu20/Screenshot%202017-02-11%2001.49.49.png?dl=0

Comment: Also, I read somewhere that the docs say the domain must be a string, **not** an IP Address.

Comment: The info from @JoshPinter worked for me with XCode 8.

Comment: This works in Xcode Version 8.2.1 (8C1002), March 2017 - Thanks.

Comment: FYI, this IS the contents of your info.plist

Answer (score 772):

See the forum post *[Application Transport Security?](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/3544)*.

For example, you can add a specific domain like:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
  <dict>
    <key>example.com</key>
    <dict>
      <!--Include to allow subdomains-->
      <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
      <true/>
      <!--Include to allow HTTP requests-->
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
      <true/>
      <!--Include to specify minimum TLS version-->
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
      <string>TLSv1.1</string>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</dict>
```

The lazy option is:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <!--Include to allow all connections (DANGER)-->
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
      <true/>
</dict>
```

###Note:

`info.plist` is an XML file so you can place this code more or less anywhere inside the file.

Comment: How can I do that, I mean what is the way to add this code to the Info.plist because I do not know where to paste this code?

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf open your info.plist in a plain text editor

Comment: Works fine for me with beta 5.
This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: The lazy options worked always. The domain option worked only if I added "www.mywebpage.com" in the .pliest file which I opened as source code. This solution worked for Xcode 7.0 beta 5 (7A176X) iOS 9.0 beta. self.thankYou("@KMLong") :)

Comment: by lazy options ,all web service working fine except one web service one web service return **internal server error (500)**  in iOS 9 but working fine in iOS8 or later

Comment: I love the lazy option ahahha :) The thing is though, what if you have lots of different website links which could potentially load.... you can't list them all.....

Comment: Probably good to show official apple docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/technotes/App-Transport-Security-Technote/

Comment: I still get the error: exception domain is set and NSAllowsArbitraryLoads is false. Even with NSAllowsArbitraryLoads set true the error shows up. Does anyone else here have this issue?

Comment: As of 1/30/2016 Apple doc shows that the keys no longer have the Temporary word in them, e.g.:
NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads
NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion
See https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html

Comment: In case anyone else is pulling their hair out because doing these simple changes to info.plist isn't working.. add the changes to Project>Target>Info>Custom iOS Target Properties

Comment: Im on XCode 7.2. Changed the keys without "Temporary" word in them. Still doesn't work. Anybody found a solution?

Comment: Thanks, mate! Worked fine on 9.2.1. Cheers.

Comment: 9.2.1 gives same error for me if i also add NSExceptionDomains after NSAllowsArbitraryLoads

Comment: Can´t use IOS simulator with this, only real devices

Comment: The best option for me was to make the api run in https

Answer (score 358):

This was tested and was working on iOS 9 GM seed - this is the configuration to allow a *specific* domain to use HTTP instead of HTTPS:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
      <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key> 
      <false/>
       <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
       <dict>
            <key>example.com</key> <!--Include your domain at this line -->
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                <string>TLSv1.1</string>
            </dict>
       </dict>
</dict>
```

`NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` must be `false`, because it disallows **all** insecure connection, but the exceptions list allows connection to **some** domains without HTTPS.

Here it is visually:

[image: Info.plist structure]

Comment: THIS should be marked as the answer.  Tested and working on iOS 9 GM seed to allow a specific domain to use http without taking the "lazy" way and completely opening your app up.

Comment: How do I add this to my info.plist?

Comment: If you open info.plist with sublime text app then you get the xml

Comment: Ok I added that entry to my info.plist and I'm still getting this error - " App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file."

Comment: Thank you this works! Looks like the NSAllowsArbitraryLoads = False is required for the NSExceptionDomains to work.

Comment: does not work on 9.1 tvOS , tryng to open this link NSURL *videourl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://<user>:<password>@mysubdomain.myserver.com/cam1/video.cgi"];

Comment: @user30646 Did you change the domain? yourdomain.com should be changed to "whatever your domain is"

Comment: What if I don’t have a domain name and just use an IP address?

Comment: @RomanShapovalov Using IP addresses is strongly not recommended because all iOS apps must conform IPv6, see Apple Docs about this

Comment: @RomanShapovalov if you must use an IP address, try adding .xip.io to the end of the IP address and add xip.io to your NSExceptionDomains.  See http://xip.io.  I connect directly to IP when developing (but not release) and this works great for me.

Comment: this should be the correct answer. The accepted answer sets NSAllowsArbitraryLoads to true, which allows urls through from any domain. It should be set to false

Comment: Wasn't working for me until I realised I had put it in the wrong info.plist in my test project. Make sure you put it in the right one!

Comment: @ConsBulaquena, it will go inside your `Info.plist` file.

Comment: Still helps, 2020/05/03, Xcode 11.3.1, logically this makes sense, practically it works (adding exception while setting `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads ` to `NO`)

Answer (score 151):

This is a quick workaround (but not recommended) to add this in the plist:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Which means (according to [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/technotes/App-Transport-Security-Technote/)):

> NSAllowsArbitraryLoads 
>   A Boolean value used to disable App Transport Security for any domains not listed in the NSExceptionDomains dictionary. Listed domains use the settings specified for that domain.
>
> The default value of NO requires the default App Transport Security behaviour for all connections.

I really recommend links:

- [Apple's technical note](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/technotes/App-Transport-Security-Technote/)
- [WWDC 2015 session 706 (Security and Your Apps)](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=706) starts around 1:50
- [WWDC 2015 session 711 (Networking with NSURLSession)](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-711/)
- Blog post *[Shipping an App With App Transport Security](http://timekl.com/blog/2015/08/21/shipping-an-app-with-app-transport-security/)*

which help me understand reasons and all the implications.

The XML (in file Info.plist) below will:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <false/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>PAGE_FOR_WHICH_SETTINGS_YOU_WANT_TO_OVERRIDE</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

disallow arbitrary calls for all pages, but for `PAGE_FOR_WHICH_SETTINGS_YOU_WANT_TO_OVERRIDE` will allow that connections use the HTTP protocol.

To the XML above you can add:

```
<key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
<true/>
```

if you want to allow insecure connections for the subdomains of the specified address.

The best approach is to block all arbitrary loads (set to false) and add exceptions to allow only addresses we know are fine.

[For interested readers](https://www.dzombak.com/blog/2015/09/Nobody-is-using-App-Transport-Security--what-s-next-.html)

***2018 Update:***

Apple is not recommending switching this off - more information can be found in [207 session WWDC 2018](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/207/) with more things explained in regards to security

Leaving the original answer for historic reasons and development phase

Comment: `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` must be `false`

Comment: @SoundBlaster for what case and what you see wrong in my answer to down vote?

Comment: by adding in plist(NSAppTransportSecurity NSAllowsArbitraryLoads), all web service working fine except one web service one web service return internal server error (500) in iOS 9 but working fine in iOS8 or later

Comment: @SoundBlaster made a change, now you shouldn't have objections :)

Comment: Thanks, how do you actually add the `<key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
<true/>` ? Does every setting have to be surrounded by `<dict>`? how do you edit this damn plist file? What's the formatting? :D Thank you.

Answer (score 121):

For those of you who want a more context on ***why*** this is happening, in addition to how to fix it, then read below.

With the introduction of iOS 9, to improve the security of connections between an app and web services, *secure connections between an app and its web service must follow best practices*. The best practices behavior is enforced by the **App Transport Security** to:

- prevent accidental disclosure, and
- provide a default behavior that is secure.

As explained in the [App Transport Security Technote](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/technotes/App-Transport-Security-Technote/), when communicating with your web service, App Transport Security now has the following requirements and behavior:

> - The server must support at least Transport Layer Security (TLS) protocol version 1.2.
> - Connection ciphers are limited to those that provide forward secrecy (see the list of ciphers below.)
> - Certificates must be signed using a SHA256 or better signature hash algorithm, with either a 2048 bit or greater RSA key or a 256 bit or
>     greater Elliptic-Curve (ECC) key.
> - Invalid certificates result in a hard failure and no connection.

In other words, your web service request should: a.) use *HTTPS* and b.) be encrypted using TLS v1.2 with forward secrecy.

However, as was mentioned in other posts, you can override this new behavior from App Transport Security by specifying the insecure domain in the `Info.plist` of your app.

---

To override, you will need to add the `NSAppTransportSecurity` > `NSExceptionDomains` dictionary properties to your `Info.plist`. Next, you will add your web service's domain to the `NSExceptionDomains` dictionary.

For example, if I want to bypass the App Transport Security behavior for a web service on the host **www.yourwebservicehost.com** then I would do the following:

1. Open your app in Xcode.
2. Find the `Info.plist` file in Project Navigator and "right-mouse" click on it and choose the *Open As* > *Source Code* menu option. The property list file will appear in the right pane.
3. Put the following properties block inside of the main properties dictionary (under the first `<dict>`).

---

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>www.example.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.1</string>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

If you need to provide exceptions for additional domains then you would add another dictionary property beneath `NSExceptionDomains`.

To find out more about the keys referenced above, read [this already mentioned technote](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/technotes/App-Transport-Security-Technote/).

Comment: This worked in 2 of my apps, but it's not working on a 3rd one. Has anyone else encountered a situation of using the above fix and still getting the same error message? (and yes I updated the dictionary to use my API domain, not the one in the code)

Comment: Best ! Apple confirms that this solution using

Comment: This worked for a Cordova/Phonegap/Ionic app editing file `./platforms/ios/<project>/<project>-Info.plist` with `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads=false` and many exception domains to services with varying TLS/HTTP/HTTPS combinations. Initially used `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads=true` then adjusted, troubleshooting the rules through trial and error to comply with guidelines and submit for approval. Note `config.xml` `<access origin=.../>` statements partially populate this file, but currently requires adjustment by direct editing or via XCode to get the details correct.

Comment: Also `<access origin="*"/>` (in config.xml) sets `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads=true` (for Cordova/Phonegap/hybrid apps

Comment: Why is `NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads` set to `true`? You subvert the purpose of ATS. Also see [The most dangerous code in the world: validating SSL certificates in non-browser software](http://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/pubs/abstracts/ssl-client-bugs.html). Your software just made the list.

Answer (score 70):

I do not like editing the plist directly. You can easily add it to the plist using the GUI:

- Click on the Info.plist in the Navigator on the left.
- Now change the data in the main area:

  - On the last line add the +
  - Enter the name of the group: **App Transport Security Settings**
  - Right click on the group and select `Add Row`
  - Enter **Allow Arbitrary Loads**
  - Set the value on the right to **YES**

[image: Example]

Comment: To clarify: if "Allow Arbitrary Loads" is YES, and there are "Exception Domains", then the loads that are allowed are restricted to the ones in the Exception Domains. Is that correct?

Comment: is that a safe way to do it if I want to release the application?

Comment: **No.** By allowing arbitrary loads, your app can connect to any domains freely. In security point of view, you should control & limit which domain / website should the app connect to, to avoid unexpected network usage.

Comment: Most apps route only to known servers. This is controlled by the developer. So the security Issues are known.

Comment: Why is `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` set to `YES`? You subvert the purpose of ATS. Also see [The most dangerous code in the world: validating SSL certificates in non-browser software](http://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/pubs/abstracts/ssl-client-bugs.html). Your software just made the list.

Comment: Sometimes you have to access a non-secure website. In those cases you can use the code above. In all other cases using SSL is advised.

Comment: I have implemented this is multiple projects. All work. Can you give more info on your case?

Answer (score 29):

[image: Apple Document 1]

[image: Apple Document 2]

There are two solutions for this :

**Solutions 1 :**

1. In `Info.plist` file add a dictionary with key '`NSAppTransportSecurity`'
2. Add another element inside dictionary with key `'Allow Arbitrary Loads'`

`Plist` structure should appear as shown in below image.

[image: Solution 1]

**Solution 2 :**

1. In `Info.plist` file add a dictionary with key '`NSAppTransportSecurity`'
2. Add another element inside dictionary with key '`NSExceptionDomains`'
3. Add element with key `'MyDomainName.com'` of type NSDictionary
4. Add element with key '`NSIncludesSubdomains`' of type `Boolean` and value set as `YES`
5. Add element with key '`NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads`' of type `Boolean` and value set as `YES`

`Plist` structure should appear as shown in below image.

[image: Solution 2]

*Solution 2 is preferred since it allows only selected domain whereas solution 1 allows all insecure HTTP connections.*

Comment: Why is `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` set to `YES`? You subvert the purpose of ATS. Also see [The most dangerous code in the world: validating SSL certificates in non-browser software](http://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/pubs/abstracts/ssl-client-bugs.html). Your software just made the list.

Answer (score 23):

## ⛔️ Don't use bad practices!

Many of the answers (including the accepted one) tell you to make your app's network communication entirely **unsecured!** by setting the `Allow Arbitrary Loads` to `Yes` (or `true`). That is the most dangerous setting for network requests! And it is **ONLY** for testing and temporary purposes.

You can see this Apple Engineer clearly saying this in **[here in WWDC18](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/207/?time=312)** even for Web Content and you are trying to allow them all!
[image]

---

#### ✅ Set `Allow Arbitrary Loads` to `NO` !!!

You must always use `HTTPS` for your networking stuff. But if you really can't, just add an exception to the `info.plist`

For example, if you are using `http://google.com` and getting that error, You **MUST** change it to `https://google.com` (with **s**) since it supports perfectly.

But if you can't somehow, (and you cant convince backend developers to support SSL), add JUST this **unsecured** domain to the `info.plist` (instead of making it available for **ALL UNSECURE NET!**)

[image: Expception]

Answer (score 22):

Transport security is available on iOS 9.0 or later. You may have this warning when trying to call a WS inside your application:

> Application Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file.

Adding the following to your Info.plist will disable ATS:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
     <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/>
</dict>
```

Comment: NSAllowsArbitraryLoads must be false, if true it allows all insecure connection

Comment: by adding in plist all web service working fine except one web service one web service return internal server error (500) in iOS 9 but working fine in iOS8 or later

Comment: Accepted on the store?

Comment: Very bad advice; see [The most dangerous code in the world: validating SSL certificates in non-browser software](http://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/pubs/abstracts/ssl-client-bugs.html). Given the question if full of the recommended way to do things, "me too" answers like this are not needed.

Answer (score 16):

### Development Example

Here is a screenshot of a plist which keeps ATS intact (=secure), but allows that connections to **localhost** can be made via **HTTP instead of HTTPS**. It works in Xcode 7.1.1.

[image]

Comment: Are there any ways to make localhost secure, i.e. using HTTPS, in react-native so that we do not have to use the default `NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads - YES` config?

Answer (score 16):

According to Apple, generally disabling ATS will lead to app rejection, unless you have a good reason to do so. Even then, you should add exceptions for domains that you can access safely.

Apple has an excellent tool that tells you exactly what settings to use: In Terminal, enter

```
/usr/bin/nscurl --ats-diagnostics --verbose https://www.example.com/whatever
```

and nscurl will check whether this request fails, and then try a variety of settings and tell you exactly which one passes, and what to do. For example, for some third-party URL that I visit, this command told me that this dictionary passes:

```
{
    NSExceptionDomains = {
        "www.example.com" = {
            NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy = false;
        };
    };
}
```

To distinguish between your own sites and third-party sites that are out of your control, use, for example, the key NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy.

Comment: its great tool to check before actually test with the application. save time. but any resource to read to understand the out put of this command.

Comment: Interesting tool. In my case it overstates things though. It lists three keys including `NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads = true;`, but it turns out that one's not needed.

Answer (score 14):

Go to your Info.plist

1. Right Click on empty space and Click on Add Row
2. Write the Key Name as NSAppTransportSecurity, Under it
3. Select Exception Domains, Add a new item to this
4. Write down your domain name that needs to get accessed
5. Change the Domain type from String to Dictionary, add a new Item
6. NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads, that will be a boolean with a true value.
   [image: Look at the picture to follow it correctly]

Comment: Why is `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` set to `true`? You subvert the purpose of ATS. Also see [The most dangerous code in the world: validating SSL certificates in non-browser software](http://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/pubs/abstracts/ssl-client-bugs.html). Your software just made the list.

Answer (score 12):

Figuring out what settings to use can be performed automatically, as mentioned in [this technote](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/technotes/App-Transport-Security-Technote/index.html):

```
/usr/bin/nscurl --ats-diagnostics --verbose https://your-domain.com
```

Comment: You do need OS X 10.11 (El Capitan) for this, apparently.

Answer (score 11):

NOTE: The exception domain in your plist should be in LOWER-CASE.

Example: you have named your machine "MyAwesomeMacbook" under Settings->Sharing; your server (for test purposes) is running on MyAwesomeMacbook.local:3000, and your app needs to send a request to http://MyAwesomeMacbook.local:3000/files..., your plist you will need to specify "myawesomemacbook.local" as the exception domain.

--

Your info.plist would contain...

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
  <dict>
    <key>myawesomemacbook.local</key>
    <dict>
      <!--Include to allow subdomains-->
      <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
      <true/>
      <!--Include to allow HTTP requests-->
      <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
      <true/>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</dict>
```

Answer (score 10):

On 2015-09-25 (after Xcode updates on 2015-09-18):

I used a non-lazy method, but it didn't work. The followings are my tries.

First,

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>www.xxx.yyy.zzz</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.1</string>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

And second,

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>www.xxx.yyy.zzz</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.1</string>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Finally, I used the lazy method:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

It might be a little insecure, but I couldn't find other solutions.

Comment: Why is `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` set to `true`? You subvert the purpose of ATS. Also see [The most dangerous code in the world: validating SSL certificates in non-browser software](http://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/pubs/abstracts/ssl-client-bugs.html). Your software just made the list.

Answer (score 9):

Use:

[image: PList Screenshot to understand better]

Add a new item, **NSAppTransportSecurity**, in the plist file with type **Dictionary**, then add sub item **NSAllowsArbitraryLoads** in dictionary of type **Boolean**, and set bool value **YES**. This works for me.

Comment: NSAllowsArbitraryLoads must be false, if true it allows all insecure connection

Comment: by adding in plist all web service working fine except one web service one web service  return ***internal server error (500)***  in iOS 9 but working fine in iOS8  or later  @ThiagoArreguy

Comment: Very bad advice; see [The most dangerous code in the world: validating SSL certificates in non-browser software](http://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/pubs/abstracts/ssl-client-bugs.html). Given the question if full of the recommended way to do things, "me too" answers like this are not needed.

Comment: I Know its a bad advice, but it's just a solution for the time being in development mode only. Apple has provided us flexibility, if its that much bad, they wouldn't allow this.

Answer (score 9):

In swift 4 and xocde 10 is change the NSAllowsArbitraryLoads to Allow Arbitrary Loads. so it is going to be look like this :

```
<key>App Transport Security Settings</key>
<dict>
     <key>Allow Arbitrary Loads</key><true/>
</dict>
```

Answer (score 6):

It may be worth mentioning how to get there...

Info.plist is one of the files below the Main.storyboard or viewController.swift.

When you click on it the first time, it usually is in a table format, so right click the file and 'open as' Source code and then add the code below towards the end, i.e.:

```
 <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key><dict><key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/></dict>
```

Copy paste the code just above

```
 "</dict>
</plist>"
```

which is at the end.

Comment: Why is `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` set to `true`? You subvert the purpose of ATS. Also see [The most dangerous code in the world: validating SSL certificates in non-browser software](http://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/pubs/abstracts/ssl-client-bugs.html). Your software just made the list.

Answer (score 6):

> **How to fix it?**

[image]

> **Below steps to fix it.**

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5):

Update for Xcode 7.1, facing problem 27.10.15:

The new value in the Info.plist is "App Transport Security Settings".
From there, this dictionary should contain:

- Allow Arbitrary Loads = YES
- Exception Domains (insert here your http domain)

Answer (score 5):

For those who came here trying to find the reason why their WKWebView is always white and loads nothing (exactly as described here [how do I get WKWebView to work in swift and for an macOS App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44465974/how-do-i-get-wkwebview-to-work-in-swift-and-for-an-macos-app#)) :

If all the rocket science above does not work for you check the obvious: the sandbox settings

[image: sandbox settings]]

Being new to swift and cocoa, but pretty experienced in programming I've spend about 20 hours to find this solution. None of dozens hipster-iOS-tutorials nor apple keynotes – nothing mentions this small checkbox.

Comment: Oh my god, thank you so much! You saved me the same 20 hour search!

Comment: not seeing that section in the Capabilities section of the target (Xcode 9.4.1)

Answer (score 3):

By default, iOS only allows HTTPS API. Since HTTP is not secure, you will have to disable App transport security. There are two ways to disable ATS:-

> **1. Adding source code in project info.plist and add the following code in root   tag.**

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

> **2. Using project info.**

Click on project on the project on the left pane, select the project as target and choose info tab. You have to add the dictionary in the following structure.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

** Finally!!! Resolved App transport Security **

```
  1. Follow the follow the screen shot. Do it in Targets info Section.
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In `Swift 5` we have two way to overcome this problem. we need to add the `NSAppTransportSecurity` in `info.plist`

I give the `info.plist` sourcecode and image for reference

First one is Add the `NSAppTransportSecurity` -> `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` in `info.plist`.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <false/>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Another one method is Add the `NSAppTransportSecurity` -> `NSExceptionDomains` in `info.plist` and add the domain of the URL and enable the permissions to load there sub-domains(`NSIncludesSubdomains`) and Allow the insecure HTTP loads(`NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads`)

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
      <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
      <dict>
        <key>www.7timer.info</key>
        <dict>
          <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
          <true/>
          <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
          <true/>
        </dict>
      </dict>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `NSExceptionDomains` may not apply an effect simultaneously due to target site may load resources (e.g. `js` files) from external domains over `http`. It can be resolved by adding these external domains to `NSExceptionDomains` as well.

To inspect which resources cannot be loaded try to use Remote debugging. Here is a tutorial: http://geeklearning.io/apache-cordova-and-remote-debugging-on-ios/

Answer (score 0):

For Cordova, if you want to add it into your ios.json, do the following:

```
"NSAppTransportSecurity": [
   {
      "xml": "<dict><key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true /></dict>"
   }
]
```

And it should be inside of:

```
"*-Info.plist": {
   "parents": {
   }
}
```

Comment: Just <access origin="*" /> in config.xml didn't work. Not sure if both are necessary, but the ios.json solution sealed the deal for me.

Comment: Why is `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` set to `true`? You subvert the purpose of ATS. Also see [The most dangerous code in the world: validating SSL certificates in non-browser software](http://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/pubs/abstracts/ssl-client-bugs.html). Your software just made the list.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open info.plist file
2. Add a Key called `App Transport Security Settings` as a Dictionary.
3. Add a Subkey called `Allow Arbitrary Loads` as Boolean and set its value to YES as in the following image.
4. Finally, clean the Project (with Command+Shift+K) and done.

[image: image of the solution in info.plist]

Or, in code:

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>

    // .....

</dict>
```

Comment: Please do not post duplicate answers.

Answer (score -1):

Like many have noted, this is a feature issue that comes with iOS 9.0. They have added a thing called App Transport Security, and I too was annoyed when it broke my Apps.

You can bandage it with the NSAllowsArbitraryLoads key to YES under NSAppTransportSecurity dictionary in your .plist file, but ultimately you will need to re-write the code that forms your URLs to form the HTTPS:// prefix.

Apple has re-written the NSUrlConnection class in iOS 9.0. You can read about it in *[NSURLConnection](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003755)*.

Else, you may have to back out of iOS 9.0 until you have time to implement the correct solution.