# How do I load an HTTPS URL in iOS 9?

Tags: ios, objective-c

What setting do I need to put in my info.plist to enable HTTPS mode? I've already put this in my plist:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

But it's not working, I'm still getting this error

> Error Message:-
>
> 2016-02-25 12:46:31.860 Indus Audio[707:13224] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)
>
> 2016-02-25 14:20:31.119 Indus Audio[817:23670] Response:(null) Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1202 "The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “www.indusaudio.com” which could put your confidential information at risk."
>
> UserInfo={NSURLErrorFailingURLPeerTrustErrorKey=, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9813, 
>   NSErrorPeerCertificateChainKey={type = immutable, count = 1, values = (
>       0 : 
>   )}, NSUnderlyingError=0x7f9e58e05cf0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1202 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0, kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerTrust=, _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9813, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9813, kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerCertificates={type = immutable, count = 1, values = (
>       0 : 
>   )}}},

URL: `https://www.xxxxx.com/xxx/xxx/files/downloadFile/en/linto`

Comment: This question has the exact same error code: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21025622/433373

Comment: Given the error code, your server is most probably missing an intermediate certificate. What happens if you open the same URL in Safari iOS, Safari Mac, or another browser?

Comment: actually i used to open these URL via one extension is called Advanced client in chrome.There  it will works fine and these URL is working in android perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**
Better update your server to support SSL and TLSv1.2

Use this for **temporary** use only. This method isn't totally advisable:

```
   <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <!--Connect to anything. Not advisable. For desperate measures I guess-->
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

**Original Answer:**

iOS 9 supports TLSv1.2, see [this document](http://ste.vn/2015/06/10/configuring-app-transport-security-ios-9-osx-10-11/). So by changing it to TLSv1.1, it bypasses the security (which is not that completely advisable). Also, specify your `url` like this:

```
 <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
  <dict>
    <key>enterYourUrlHere.com</key>
    <dict>
      <!--Include to allow subdomains-->
      <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
      <true/>
      <!--Include to allow HTTP requests-->
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
      <true/>
      <!--Include to specify minimum TLS version-->
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
      <string>TLSv1.1</string>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</dict>
```

Comment: instead of `https://www.xxxxx.com/xxx/xxx/files/downloadFile/en/linto`, try `http://www.xxxxx.com/xxx/xxx/files/downloadFile/en/linto`

Comment: i tried but backend is not supporting http as well as https

Comment: I've updated my answer but please consider updating your server.

Answer (score -1):

Add **App Transport Security Settings** in info.plist file and set **Allow Arbitrary Loads** item to YES.

Comment: can u tell me how can i add these information in my plist

Comment: You can just add "App Transport Security Settings" key and add nested key "Allow Arbitrary Loads" then set it to YES.

Comment: This would allow your app to connect to any URL, its not a secure way to do a job